# Unexpected EOF in attribute value at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [2,3861] issue with web service reply in TIBCO BW 6.3

Tags: tibco, tibco-business-works

When invoking a web service from TIBCO BW 6.3.3, getting error in the reply message.  The error log as follows:

Can anyone please guide me to resolve the issue.

```
ERROR [Axis2 Task] com.tibco.bw.binding.soap - TIBCO-BW-BINDING-               SOAP-550120: Error occurred while processing reply message from the service provider of the Operation [{urn:GenericSoap}GenericSoapOperation], SoapReferenceBinding [SOAPReferenceBinding], Application [webCenter.application:1.0] due to exception [org.apache.axiom.om.OMException]
15:11:51.647 ERROR [Axis2 Task] com.tibco.bw.binding.soap - com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException: Unexpected EOF in attribute value
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [2,3861]
[Fatal Error] :1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] :1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] :1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] :1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] :1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] :1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] :1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
[Fatal Error] :1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.

15:11:51.673 ERROR [bwEngThread:In-Memory Process Worker-7]   com.tibco.bw.core - TIBCO-BW-CORE-500050: The BW process [webcenter.Process] instance faulted, JobId [bw0a100], ProcessInstanceId [bw0a100], ParentProcessInstanceId [-], Module [webCenter:1.0.0.qualifier], Application [webCenter.application:1.0].  
<CausedBy> TIBCO-BW-CORE-500052: Invoke activity [GenericSoapOperation] fault.  
<CausedBy> com.tibco.bw.binding.soap.BWSOAPReferenceBindingException: TIBCO-BW-BINDING-SOAP-550120: Error occurred while processing reply message from the service provider of the Operation [{urn:GenericSoap}GenericSoapOperation], SoapReferenceBinding [SOAPReferenceBinding], Application [webCenter.application:1.0] due to exception [org.apache.axiom.om.OMException]
<CausedBy> org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException: Unexpected EOF in attribute value


at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [2,3861]
    <CausedBy> com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException: Unexpected EOF in attribute value at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [2,3861]
```

Comment: This error means that the response received is not a soap message. Can you check the response of the web service?

Comment: The response and fault both are null.

Comment: I understood that the issue at TIBCO Bw locally.  So, to resolve this issue I have changed the Log level to "DEBUG" for SoapBinding in Logback.xml.  Then the issue got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Check the encoding in the xml/xsd file, it has to be the same

```
<?xml version="1.0" **encoding="UTF-8"?**>
```